# How to detect Multiple beacons using a single region?

Tags: android, altbeacon, gimbal

I have 2 different beacons representing a single product.I would like to group this beacon to a single region.And start monitoring that region.Is there any way to do this in android altbeacon library?

Comment: Do you know the two beacons of the same product, i mean do you have predefined list for products and beacons ?

Comment: Yes.I have a list of products and related list of beacons for each product

Comment: So you can compare with your list when app detect the beacon, i think this is so simple.

Comment: If my app detected 1000 beacons.Just for detecting 2 beacons I need to search 1000 beacons

Comment: Yes that is a fact, else you can insert into a DB and select using that beacon id or some thing